# TortoiseHg Push

Tags: mercurial, push, tortoisehg, bitbucket

What's the TortoiseHg equivalent of:

```
hg push http://bitbucket.org/MY_USER/MY_REPO
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in the manual, and I ask this after extensive Google searching.

What I want to do is upload my files to my Bitbucket repository, and be able to "update" them in the future.

---

**EDIT:** TortoiseHg 2.0 users, look [here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/sync.html).

Comment: @John I've fixed the broken link

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### TortoiseHg 1.x

I'm assuming you are talking about the GUI.  If so, it's "Synchronize" then that will bring up a window where you can Push.  Check out my screenshot.  There is a drop down list but to get something to display in that dropdown you have to click on Configure then add your server.  You can also just paste it where the arrow is pointing.

[image: TortoiseHg 1.0 Synchronize - http://bitbucket.org/username/repo_name]

### TortoiseHg 2.x

See [here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/sync.html).

[image: TortoiseHg 2.0 Sync - https:// bitbucket.org : /username/repo_name]

Comment: I'm not sure how push it to the URL I gave above, though.

Comment: @muntoo Hope the screenshot helps

Comment: OK, I got it. [This is for TortoiseHg 2.0](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/2.0/sync.html). I wasn't sure where to type the stuff in until I finally saw that. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: @muntoo Actually, that's my fault for not checking which version of TortoiseHg.  I completely overlooked that.  Sorry.

Comment: I hadn't looked around the manual for "Synchronize", so that's my fault. :)